# git submodule status for a given tag

Tags: git

How can I see the list (and the version/tag/last commit id) of git submodules of a given GIT repository given the tag?

Let me explain:

The repo has 2 tag:

```
[user@host foobar] (master) $ git tag
v1.0
v1.1
```

The head is 3 commit away from v1.1:

```
[user@host foobar] (master) $ git describe
v1.1-3-gbcaa726
```

The main repository contains 4 submodules:

```
[user@host foobar] (master) $ git submodule
51d91a79df12d356e2297e6d84fce92dac3ccedc roles/apache (heads/master)
4574dd38b0fce4aba68fcdea0deeed9dbe4872c3 roles/network (v1.0-1-g4574dd3)
f5a4c1ac9dfab903a2271d5036dd350f889e4f26 roles/rabbitmq (heads/master)
e6781120999aa036539955606d7d98f39bb450a5 roles/jboss-eap (heads/master)
```

The "git submodule" command show the last commit for each submodule.

What I need to do is something like

```
[user@host foobar] (master) $ git submodule --tag v.1.0
```

For printing the commit id of submodules at time of tag v.1.0

Is that possibile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a submodule doesn't have nested submodules or you don't care about it, you could run `git ls-tree -r -t v1.0 | grep ^160000` to print the commit ids of submodules at v1.0. By this method, you don't need to checkout the tag.

If you don't mind checking out the tag, you could try:

```
git checkout v1.0
git submodule update
git submodule
```